# Twitter OAuth Login and Redirect

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am attempting to automatically login to twitter using the OAUTH and php. I have successfully created the connection and can login / tweet successfully using the following code:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(
    'consumer_key', 
    'consumer_secret', 
    'oauth_token',
    'oauth_token_secret'
);
$credentials = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
echo "Connected as @" . $credentials->screen_name;
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'ello world'));
```

However, instead of tweeting I would like to redirect the user to `twitter.com`, and have them already logged in.

Is there something within the API that can allow me to do this?

Comment: if u succeed in login/tweet then there is no issue to open twitter.com, if you open twitter.com in next tab of browser then you will b automatically logged in that account.

Comment: That's what I thought, however this does not seem to be the case. I open a new tab and it is not logged in..

Comment: r u also closing twitter from API?? opening in iframe or on same page??

Comment: Not closing the connection, and opening twitter in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to log a user into twitter.com with an OAuth access token. The only way a user can get an authenticated session with twitter.com is by submitting the login form with their username/password.